# Trying to get input field text to be displayed in Uppercase

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, form, inputformtextbox

I have a list and I'd like for when users enter an ID number in the text field that it be returned in uppercase without having the user use caps lock or shift.

Comment: Can you use InfoPath forms?

Comment: CSS text transform uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a little jQuery to force the upper case. On keyup event, get the string and set it to upper case. Let me know if you could use some more help with the code.